# Python Bs4 Issue Trying to Scrape Table

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Does anyone know I how can parse the following html with bs4? I have tried to specify various css selectors and have had no luck. The data seems to be in chart.js format, which is why I can't seem to parse it. I can use selenium also, but I'm not sure that would work. The website I am trying to scrape is https://downdetector.com/status/spotify/
and I'm trying to pull all values within the chart.

'''
window.DD.chartTranlations = {
reports: "reports",
baseline: "baseline",
baselineInfo: ""
}

```
  window.DD.currentServiceProperties = {
    id: 20090,
    status: 'danger',
    max_baseline: 10,
    min_baseline: 1,
    communicate: null,
    company: 'Spotify',
    max: 5341,
    series: {
      reports: {
        label: "reports",
        data: [
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T20:14:16+00:00', y: 75 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T20:29:16+00:00', y: 69 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T20:44:16+00:00', y: 64 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T20:59:16+00:00', y: 51 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T21:14:16+00:00', y: 49 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T21:29:16+00:00', y: 48 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T21:44:16+00:00', y: 76 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T21:59:16+00:00', y: 66 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T22:14:16+00:00', y: 68 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T22:29:16+00:00', y: 51 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T22:44:16+00:00', y: 57 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T22:59:16+00:00', y: 49 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T23:14:16+00:00', y: 54 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T23:29:16+00:00', y: 60 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T23:44:16+00:00', y: 50 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T23:59:16+00:00', y: 58 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T00:14:16+00:00', y: 51 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T00:29:16+00:00', y: 51 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T00:44:16+00:00', y: 40 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T00:59:16+00:00', y: 38 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T01:14:16+00:00', y: 51 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T01:29:16+00:00', y: 40 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T01:44:16+00:00', y: 37 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T01:59:16+00:00', y: 34 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T02:14:16+00:00', y: 26 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T02:29:16+00:00', y: 40 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T02:44:16+00:00', y: 34 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T02:59:16+00:00', y: 21 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T03:14:16+00:00', y: 29 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T03:29:16+00:00', y: 29 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T03:44:16+00:00', y: 19 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T03:59:16+00:00', y: 21 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T04:14:16+00:00', y: 29 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T04:29:16+00:00', y: 17 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T04:44:16+00:00', y: 23 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T04:59:16+00:00', y: 17 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T05:14:16+00:00', y: 14 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T05:29:16+00:00', y: 24 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T05:44:16+00:00', y: 23 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T05:59:16+00:00', y: 12 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T06:14:16+00:00', y: 11 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T06:29:16+00:00', y: 6 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T06:44:16+00:00', y: 4 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T06:59:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T07:14:16+00:00', y: 11 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T07:29:16+00:00', y: 0 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T07:44:16+00:00', y: 4 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T07:59:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T08:14:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T08:29:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T08:44:16+00:00', y: 6 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T08:59:16+00:00', y: 1 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T09:14:16+00:00', y: 4 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T09:29:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T09:44:16+00:00', y: 3 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T09:59:16+00:00', y: 10 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T10:14:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T10:29:16+00:00', y: 16 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T10:44:16+00:00', y: 20 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T10:59:16+00:00', y: 24 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T11:14:16+00:00', y: 25 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T11:29:16+00:00', y: 23 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T11:44:16+00:00', y: 19 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T11:59:16+00:00', y: 29 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T12:14:16+00:00', y: 26 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T12:29:16+00:00', y: 27 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T12:44:16+00:00', y: 22 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T12:59:16+00:00', y: 23 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T13:14:16+00:00', y: 21 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T13:29:16+00:00', y: 41 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T13:44:16+00:00', y: 26 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T13:59:16+00:00', y: 27 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T14:14:16+00:00', y: 26 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T14:29:16+00:00', y: 23 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T14:44:16+00:00', y: 35 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T14:59:16+00:00', y: 24 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T15:14:16+00:00', y: 38 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T15:29:16+00:00', y: 35 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T15:44:16+00:00', y: 34 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T15:59:16+00:00', y: 26 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T16:14:16+00:00', y: 29 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T16:29:16+00:00', y: 21 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T16:44:16+00:00', y: 31 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T16:59:16+00:00', y: 31 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:14:16+00:00', y: 17 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:29:16+00:00', y: 14 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:44:16+00:00', y: 14 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:59:16+00:00', y: 207 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:14:16+00:00', y: 823 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:29:16+00:00', y: 1605 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:44:16+00:00', y: 4797 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:59:16+00:00', y: 5341 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T19:14:16+00:00', y: 2943 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T19:29:16+00:00', y: 3468 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T19:44:16+00:00', y: 5184 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T19:59:16+00:00', y: 2345 },
          
        ],
      },
      baseline: {
        label: "baseline",
        data: [
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T20:14:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T20:29:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T20:44:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T20:59:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T21:14:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T21:29:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T21:44:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T21:59:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T22:14:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T22:29:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T22:44:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T22:59:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T23:14:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T23:29:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T23:44:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-15T23:59:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T00:14:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T00:29:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T00:44:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T00:59:16+00:00', y: 4 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T01:14:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T01:29:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T01:44:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T01:59:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T02:14:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T02:29:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T02:44:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T02:59:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T03:14:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T03:29:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T03:44:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T03:59:16+00:00', y: 6 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T04:14:16+00:00', y: 6 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T04:29:16+00:00', y: 6 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T04:44:16+00:00', y: 6 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T04:59:16+00:00', y: 6 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T05:14:16+00:00', y: 6 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T05:29:16+00:00', y: 5 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T05:44:16+00:00', y: 5 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T05:59:16+00:00', y: 5 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T06:14:16+00:00', y: 4 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T06:29:16+00:00', y: 4 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T06:44:16+00:00', y: 4 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T06:59:16+00:00', y: 4 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T07:14:16+00:00', y: 3 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T07:29:16+00:00', y: 3 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T07:44:16+00:00', y: 3 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T07:59:16+00:00', y: 3 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T08:14:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T08:29:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T08:44:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T08:59:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T09:14:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T09:29:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T09:44:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T09:59:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T10:14:16+00:00', y: 1 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T10:29:16+00:00', y: 1 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T10:44:16+00:00', y: 1 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T10:59:16+00:00', y: 1 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T11:14:16+00:00', y: 1 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T11:29:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T11:44:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T11:59:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T12:14:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T12:29:16+00:00', y: 2 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T12:44:16+00:00', y: 3 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T12:59:16+00:00', y: 3 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T13:14:16+00:00', y: 3 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T13:29:16+00:00', y: 4 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T13:44:16+00:00', y: 4 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T13:59:16+00:00', y: 5 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T14:14:16+00:00', y: 5 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T14:29:16+00:00', y: 6 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T14:44:16+00:00', y: 6 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T14:59:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T15:14:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T15:29:16+00:00', y: 7 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T15:44:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T15:59:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T16:14:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T16:29:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T16:44:16+00:00', y: 8 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T16:59:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:14:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:29:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:44:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:59:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:14:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:29:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:44:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:59:16+00:00', y: 10 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T19:14:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T19:29:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T19:44:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T19:59:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
        ]
      },
    }
  }
</script>'''
```

Comment: The chart is just a `<canvas>` element, and you can't really parse it with bs4. But if you can get to the data you've shown in your Python code, you can just parse it a JSON.

Comment: how can I parse it as a json? It doesn't seem to work at all @tromgy

Comment: am not sure which data you are trying to pickup ?

Comment: I am trying to scrape the chart on the following webpage https://downdetector.com/status/spotify/ @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη

Comment: @RexG, yes it is more complicated. so you got the contents of the `<script>` tag, you could modify it a bit to make it executable in node, make it write out JSON, save as .js file, run node with it, and you would get a JSON file that you can parse. This will be a multi-step process: python -> node -> python, so you'll need some top-level script to coordinate all that.

Comment: @tromgy no need for all of that!

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
import re
import chompjs
from pprint import pp

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    match = re.search(
        r'currentServiceProperties = ({.*?)\<', r.text, re.DOTALL).group(1)

    x = chompjs.parse_js_object(match)

    pp(x)


main('https://downdetector.com/status/spotify/')
```

Output:

```
{'id': 20090,
 'status': 'danger',
 'max_baseline': 10,
 'min_baseline': 1,
 'communicate': None,
 'company': 'Spotify',
 'max': 5397,
 'series': {'reports': {'label': 'reports',
                        'data': [{'x': '2021-09-15T20:55:41+00:00', 'y': 58},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-15T21:10:41+00:00', 'y': 48},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-15T21:25:41+00:00', 'y': 52},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-15T21:40:41+00:00', 'y': 75},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-15T21:55:41+00:00', 'y': 64},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-15T22:10:41+00:00', 'y': 67},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-15T22:25:41+00:00', 'y': 51},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-15T22:40:41+00:00', 'y': 53},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-15T22:55:41+00:00', 'y': 54},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-15T23:10:41+00:00', 'y': 56},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-15T23:25:41+00:00', 'y': 54},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-15T23:40:41+00:00', 'y': 55},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-15T23:55:41+00:00', 'y': 56},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T00:10:41+00:00', 'y': 50},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T00:25:41+00:00', 'y': 56},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T00:40:41+00:00', 'y': 40},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T00:55:41+00:00', 'y': 34},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T01:10:41+00:00', 'y': 51},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T01:25:41+00:00', 'y': 42},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T01:40:41+00:00', 'y': 36},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T01:55:41+00:00', 'y': 36},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T02:10:41+00:00', 'y': 25},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T02:25:41+00:00', 'y': 41},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T02:40:41+00:00', 'y': 34},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T02:55:41+00:00', 'y': 20},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T03:10:41+00:00', 'y': 29},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T03:25:41+00:00', 'y': 28},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T03:40:41+00:00', 'y': 19},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T03:55:41+00:00', 'y': 23},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T04:10:41+00:00', 'y': 28},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T04:25:41+00:00', 'y': 17},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T04:40:41+00:00', 'y': 24},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T04:55:41+00:00', 'y': 18},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T05:10:41+00:00', 'y': 13},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T05:25:41+00:00', 'y': 19},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T05:40:41+00:00', 'y': 29},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T05:55:41+00:00', 'y': 11},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T06:10:41+00:00', 'y': 10},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T06:25:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T06:40:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T06:55:41+00:00', 'y': 10},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T07:10:41+00:00', 'y': 10},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T07:25:41+00:00', 'y': 1},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T07:40:41+00:00', 'y': 4},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T07:55:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T08:10:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T08:25:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T08:40:41+00:00', 'y': 6},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T08:55:41+00:00', 'y': 1},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T09:10:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T09:25:41+00:00', 'y': 10},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T09:40:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T09:55:41+00:00', 'y': 11},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T10:10:41+00:00', 'y': 6},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T10:25:41+00:00', 'y': 17},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T10:40:41+00:00', 'y': 21},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T10:55:41+00:00', 'y': 23},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T11:10:41+00:00', 'y': 26},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T11:25:41+00:00', 'y': 23},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T11:40:41+00:00', 'y': 17},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T11:55:41+00:00', 'y': 27},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T12:10:41+00:00', 'y': 28},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T12:25:41+00:00', 'y': 29},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T12:40:41+00:00', 'y': 22},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T12:55:41+00:00', 'y': 23},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T13:10:41+00:00', 'y': 20},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T13:25:41+00:00', 'y': 41},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T13:40:41+00:00', 'y': 25},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T13:55:41+00:00', 'y': 29},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T14:10:41+00:00', 'y': 25},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T14:25:41+00:00', 'y': 24},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T14:40:41+00:00', 'y': 30},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T14:55:41+00:00', 'y': 29},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T15:10:41+00:00', 'y': 35},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T15:25:41+00:00', 'y': 36},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T15:40:41+00:00', 'y': 32},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T15:55:41+00:00', 'y': 27},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T16:10:41+00:00', 'y': 31},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T16:25:41+00:00', 'y': 18},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T16:40:41+00:00', 'y': 35},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T16:55:41+00:00', 'y': 28},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T17:10:41+00:00', 'y': 20},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T17:25:41+00:00', 'y': 12},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T17:40:41+00:00', 'y': 15},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T17:55:41+00:00', 'y': 170},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T18:10:41+00:00', 'y': 784},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T18:25:41+00:00', 'y': 1467},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T18:40:41+00:00', 'y': 4621},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T18:55:41+00:00', 'y': 5397},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T19:10:41+00:00', 'y': 3105},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T19:25:41+00:00', 'y': 3351},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T19:40:41+00:00', 'y': 5104},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T19:55:41+00:00', 'y': 2665},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T20:10:41+00:00', 'y': 579},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T20:25:41+00:00', 'y': 444},
                                 {'x': '2021-09-16T20:40:41+00:00', 'y': 238}]},
            'baseline': {'label': 'baseline',
                         'data': [{'x': '2021-09-15T20:55:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-15T21:10:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-15T21:25:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-15T21:40:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-15T21:55:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-15T22:10:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-15T22:25:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-15T22:40:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-15T22:55:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-15T23:10:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-15T23:25:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-15T23:40:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-15T23:55:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T00:10:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T00:25:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T00:40:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T00:55:41+00:00', 'y': 4},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T01:10:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T01:25:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T01:40:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T01:55:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T02:10:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T02:25:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T02:40:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T02:55:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T03:10:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T03:25:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T03:40:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T03:55:41+00:00', 'y': 6},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T04:10:41+00:00', 'y': 6},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T04:25:41+00:00', 'y': 6},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T04:40:41+00:00', 'y': 6},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T04:55:41+00:00', 'y': 6},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T05:10:41+00:00', 'y': 6},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T05:25:41+00:00', 'y': 5},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T05:40:41+00:00', 'y': 5},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T05:55:41+00:00', 'y': 5},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T06:10:41+00:00', 'y': 4},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T06:25:41+00:00', 'y': 4},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T06:40:41+00:00', 'y': 4},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T06:55:41+00:00', 'y': 4},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T07:10:41+00:00', 'y': 3},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T07:25:41+00:00', 'y': 3},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T07:40:41+00:00', 'y': 3},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T07:55:41+00:00', 'y': 3},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T08:10:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T08:25:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T08:40:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T08:55:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T09:10:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T09:25:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T09:40:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T09:55:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T10:10:41+00:00', 'y': 1},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T10:25:41+00:00', 'y': 1},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T10:55:41+00:00', 'y': 1},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T11:10:41+00:00', 'y': 1},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T11:25:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T11:40:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T11:55:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T12:10:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T12:25:41+00:00', 'y': 2},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T12:40:41+00:00', 'y': 3},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T12:55:41+00:00', 'y': 3},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T13:10:41+00:00', 'y': 3},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T13:25:41+00:00', 'y': 4},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T13:40:41+00:00', 'y': 4},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T13:55:41+00:00', 'y': 5},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T14:10:41+00:00', 'y': 5},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T14:25:41+00:00', 'y': 6},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T14:40:41+00:00', 'y': 6},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T14:55:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T15:10:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T15:25:41+00:00', 'y': 7},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T15:40:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T15:55:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T16:10:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T16:25:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T16:40:41+00:00', 'y': 8},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T16:55:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T17:10:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T17:25:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T17:40:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T17:55:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T18:10:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T18:25:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T18:40:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T18:55:41+00:00', 'y': 10},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T19:10:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T19:25:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T19:40:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T19:55:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T20:10:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T20:25:41+00:00', 'y': 9},
                                  {'x': '2021-09-16T20:40:41+00:00', 'y': 9}]}}}
```

> x.keys()

```py
dict_keys(['id', 'status', 'max_baseline', 'min_baseline', 'communicate', 'company', 'max', 'series'])
```

Comment: nice! I almost suspected that something like **chompjs** should exist.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, just with using standard python modules + storing the result to pandas:

```py
import re
import ast
import pandas as pd


url = "https://downdetector.com/status/spotify/"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"
}

html_doc = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

data = {}
for l, d in re.findall(
    r'label: "(.*?)".*?data: (\[.*?\])', html_doc, flags=re.S
):
    d = re.sub(r"(x|y):", r'"\1":', d)
    data[l] = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(d))

df = pd.concat(data.values(), keys=data, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map("_".join)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                    reports_x  reports_y                 baseline_x  baseline_y
0   2021-09-15T21:06:22+00:00         54  2021-09-15T21:06:22+00:00           9
1   2021-09-15T21:21:22+00:00         53  2021-09-15T21:21:22+00:00           9
2   2021-09-15T21:36:22+00:00         74  2021-09-15T21:36:22+00:00           9
3   2021-09-15T21:51:22+00:00         53  2021-09-15T21:51:22+00:00           9
4   2021-09-15T22:06:22+00:00         74  2021-09-15T22:06:22+00:00           9
5   2021-09-15T22:21:22+00:00         51  2021-09-15T22:21:22+00:00           9
6   2021-09-15T22:36:22+00:00         53  2021-09-15T22:36:22+00:00           9

...
```