# Python BeautifulSoup scrap

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I started scrap a page from downdetector, i success to get js code from this page but not just what i want.
I have tried to specify various css selectors but its in a canvas. The data seems to be in chart.js format, which is why I can't seem to parse it.
I'm trying to pull all values within the chart

```
window.DD.currentServiceProperties = {
    id: 20090,
    status: 'danger',
    max_baseline: 10,
    min_baseline: 1,
    communicate: null,
    company: 'Spotify',
    max: 5341,
    series: {
      reports: {
        label: "reports",
        data: [
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:59:16+00:00', y: 207 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:14:16+00:00', y: 823 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:29:16+00:00', y: 1605 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:44:16+00:00', y: 4797 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:59:16+00:00', y: 5341 },          
        ],
      },
      baseline: {
        label: "baseline",
        data: [
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T16:59:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:14:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:29:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:44:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T17:59:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
            { x: '2021-09-16T18:14:16+00:00', y: 9 },
          
        ]
      },
    }
  }
```

And i expect to only get

```
label: "reports",
        data: [

            { x: '2021-09-15T20:14:16+00:00', y: 75 },
           [...]
label: "baseline",
        data: [

            { x: '2021-09-15T20:14:16+00:00', y: 9 },
           [...]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Bs4 Issue Trying to Scrape Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214706/python-bs4-issue-trying-to-scrape-table)

Comment: And your code and the url?